Stock SwiftData App with NavigationSplitView for both iPhone and iPad support crashes when last item in the list is removed
I am running the boiler plate App created by Xcode using SwiftData and I am trying to support iPhone and iPad in the same view.  I have NavigationSplitView with a List and inside that is a forEach with a .onDelete(perform:).  Problem is when I delete the last item in the SwiftData database and tap done on the edit button the app crashes.  Here is the view code:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
                            do {
                                    try modelContext.save()
                            } catch {
                                    print(error)
                            }

            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .modelContainer(for: Item.self, inMemory: true)
}

The error is "Attempted to modify the selection of an item in an out-of-bounds section"
Using Xcode 15.4
Any help would be much appreciated!

Usually offsets have to be reversed for something like this, give that a try. This is a silly oversight. I’m sure it deletes the worn items when you select multiple

Changing the code to do a reverse offset made no difference.  The crash is still the same.

Have you tried removing the do { try modelContext.save() ...} in deleteItems. Or move this outside the for index in offsets {...}?

I can't reproduce using Xcode 16 beta so it looks like this has been fixed. As a workaround I would call try? modelContext.save() after the loop in deleteItems to see if that fixes the problem.

I've tried to call try? modelContext.save() after the loop in deleteItems, still encounter the same issue.  The original code from the Xcode template does not have the try modelContext.save() at all, and the error is still present even then.
